# What would happen if you dumped negative mass into an extremal black hole?

Tags: black-holes, mass, event-horizon, singularities, exotic-matter

What would happen if you dumped [negative mass](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Negative_mass) into a near-extremal black hole?
It appears to me that doing this would reduce the Black hole's mass without reducing the angular momentum or charge?
Could this create a naked singularity?

Comment: What do you mean by negative mass and where would you go to find some?

Comment: From that article: "no particles are known to have negative mass" and "In such a framework [General Relativity], the runaway motion forbids the existence of negative matter.". Also from there: "I regard the runaway (or self-accelerating) motion […] so preposterous that I prefer to rule it out by supposing that inertial mass is all positive or all negative."— William B. Bonnor, in Negative mass in general relativity.

Comment: I'm not trying to be overly negative but you should just be aware that you're not guaranteed to get any sensible answers to a physics question if you start with an unphysical assumption, especially in a situation as delicate as an extremal black hole.

Comment: @Andrew - On the other hand, people do use it to design Alcubierre drives and prop open wormholes. It is reasonable to ask this kind of question about it.

Comment: @mmeent Fair enough and it seems like this question can be answered mathematically. I still would say that mmeent's answer illustrates that you *don't* get physically sensible results because you started from a physically nonsense starting point (garbage in, garbage out). And if you really take negative mass seriously, you get all kinds of instabilities (particles at rest spontaneously accelerating), so I feel this question is assuming a starting point that might not even be stable in a Universe with negative mass. But perhaps this is a matter of taste as to what questions are interesting.

Comment: The is nothing "non-mainstream" (in the sense set out in policy) about this question.  Asking how well established laws of physics (in this case GR) behave when relaxing some of the standard assumptions (in this case positivity of mass) is a standard and important part of theoretical physics. The particular case of the behaviour of negative mass in GR has been discussed by mainstream scientists, and has been well cited. E.g. Bondi's "Negative mass in general relativity" (https://inspirehep.net/literature/47044) has more than 150 citations in the literature.

Comment: This question can (and has been) answered using standard mainstream results about general relativity.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ignoring the plethora of theoretical problems that negative mass would cause (see examples on the Wikipedia [page's](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Negative_mass) introduction), the naive answer is yes a negative mass should be able to "overspin" (or overcharge) an (near) extremal black hole. The necessary ingredients are:

1. Small negative mass objects will still (approximately) follow geodesics of the black hole spacetime. Consequently, if you send a negative mass object on a radial trajectory along the symmetry axis towards the black hole, it will invariably fall into the black hole. A negative mass particle on such a trajectory will have negative energy and zero angular momentum, and thus push the total mass of the resulting "black hole" below the extremal limit.
2. Any corrections to this motion due to negative mass particles own gravitational field (i.e. the gravitational self-force) are order of the ratio of the masses of the small object and the black hole. Consequently, we can make then negligibly small by choosing a suitably large black hole. Note that the parameter space of geodesics that would overspin the black hole is not marginal, so the self-force cannot prevent overspinning as it would in the positive mass case (as in [[1508.04031]](https://arxiv.org/abs/1508.04031)).
3. A negative mass particle would violate all [energy conditions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Energy_condition). Consequently, a negative mass particle evades the [Sorce-Wald theorem](https://arxiv.org/abs/1707.05862) that forbids overspinning (or overcharging) of the black holes in general relativity.

This should not come as a surprise since the negatice mass version of the Schwarzschild metric itself has a naked singularity.

Comment: @safesphere, 1) Why do you think it would be repulsed by a diverting force at the horizon? 2) If you would be able to overspin/overcharge a black hole, this means that the spacetime doesn't have an event horizon, and thus a distant observer can observe this happening in a finite time. 3) There is no such thing as "the coordinates of an observer".

Answer (score 7):

No answer is possible within physics because negative mass is not part of any coherent framework of physics. The only way to answer is to first invent some sort of physical theory in which negative mass is possible, and then answer within the framework of that theory. However all such theories to date have implied behaviours which are not observed (such as self-acceleration and instability of spacetime even in ordinary conditions). So they are ruled out by observation.

In quantum field theory one can encounter situations which might be deemed to involve "negative mass" but I think they are always part of some sort of integral like a path integral and the overall result is such that you cannot have a lump of stuff with negative mass, or anything like that.

Comment: I don't think there is anything substantial stopping us from addressing this question in the context of simple general relativity with perfect fluids, or even simply GR with negative mass Schwarzschild solutions.

Comment: @mmeent I take it you mean just allow a minus sign into $T^{00}$ and see what happens. What happens, as I understand it, is that the whole of spacetime becomes unstable. To avoid this you would have to modify GR in some sort of profound and complicated way.

Comment: @safesphere Yes, but the question was what happens when you throw a "negative mass" into the blackhole, so the energy density does not vanish outside the blackhole.

Comment: @AndrewSteane That type of instability only happens when you consider (quantum) fields with negative mass. There is nothing stopping you from considering for example a gas of collsionless negative mass particles (with conserved particle number).

Comment: Note that trying to considering quantum field theory coupled to GR also leads to the conclusion to on short length scales spacetime is highly unstable. This does not stop us from considering how GR works on length scales where this is irrelevant.

Comment: What do you mean by "spacetime becomes unstable?"

Comment: @blademan9999 instability is not always easy to track, and I have only read general statements about this; I have not done the calculation. It is to do with the form of the field equation, which, being a set of partial differential equations, may have solutions exhibiting behaviour where a tiny trickle of energy flows from one place, leaving negative energy behind, and the subsequent dynamics amplify the disturbance.